# Not sure why my cronjob is not running on reboot in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shell, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to set a cronjob to start network-manager at reboot with

```
@reboot root /usr/username/scripts/start-network-manager.sh
```

however its not working for some reason. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

service network-manager start
```

I'm pretty sure the path to the script is right and I can run the script manually and it works and I made sure its executable with

```
chmod +x start-network-manager.sh
```

in the directory of the script but I'm not sure why its not working.
Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: How did you add this job?

Comment: I entered 'sudo crontab -e' and put the @reboot command at the bottom of the file, then saved it, closed it and rebooted to no avail

Comment: Only crontab files in `/etc` can have a username. Anything you put in `crontab -e` will run as the user that invoked it, and can't have a username. Use `@reboot /usr/username/scripts/start-network-manager.sh` instead. If that still doesn't work, please go through the troubleshooting steps in the [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) and edit your post with your findings

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: first you should check whether cronjob is not running or script is not working correctly....add ```echo testcronjob >> /root/cronjob.test``` to your script ```start-network-manager.sh```...then reboot.....if the file ```/root/cronjob.test``` exists then cronjob is working else there is problem with your script which may need other services to start...cronjob service doesn't care about other service so you can edit cronjob init script after which services you want to start cron service